# Why is my projection interface not picked up by Spring Data REST?

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-rest

I am trying to use up projections with Spring Data REST (version 2.3.0.RELEASE). I read the [reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#projections-excerpts), and gathered that these are the parts I need:

A JPA Entity

```
@Entity
public class Project implements Serializable {

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "PROJECT_NAME")
    private String projectName;

    // ... lots and lots of other stuff
}
```

A repository that works with that entity

```
@Repository
public interface ProjectRepository extends JpaRepository<Project, Long> { }
```

And a projection to retrieve just the name for that entity

```
@Projection(name="names", types={Project.class})
public interface ProjectProjectionNamesOnly  {

  String getProjectName();
}
```

I would like to be able to optionally retrieve just a list of names of projects, and projections seemed perfectly suited to this. So with this setup, I hit my endpoint at http://localhost:9000/projects/1?projection=names. I get back ALL of the attributes and collections links, but I expected to get back just the name and self link.

I also viewed the [sample project on projections](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/rest/projections), but the example is for excerpts, which seems different from projections as it is a different section of the reference. I tried it and it didn't work anyway though.

So the question is this: How do you use spring data rest projections to retrieve just a single attribute of an entity (and its self link)?

Comment: Are you sure the projection is discovered at all? Does the `projects` link at the API root actually expose a `projection` template parameter?

Comment: I don't think it's discovered: in the docs it looks like the returned self link should be "http://localhost:9000/projects/1{?projection}" but mine is just "http://localhost:9000/projects/1"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looks like your projection definition is not even discovered and thus it doesn't get applied if you select it for the HTTP request.

For projection interfaces to be auto-discovered they need to be placed inside the very same or a sub-package of the package of the domain type they're bound to.

If you can't put the type into that location, you can manually register a projection definition on `RepositoryRestConfiguration` by calling `….projectionConfiguration().addProjection(…)`.

The reference documentation does not really mention this at the moment but there's already a ticket to get [this fixed](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-508) in future versions.

Comment: I had originally placed the projection in the same package as the repositories, placing it in a sub package of the entity's package let it be detected! Having better documentation would be a big help, glad to know it's in the works. Thanks!