# how to implement interface based projection into dto in spring data jpa with inner join query table

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have two table- one is `USERS_TAXPAYER`(contains column- `tin_no`, `zone_no` and another one is `PAYMENT_DATA` (contains column- `tin_no` , `amount` ), my goal is to calculate total amount produced by same `zone_no`(there are multiple amount under same zone), so I am using a native query in my `repository layer` in the spring boot project like this-

```
@Query(value = "select USERS_TAXPAYER.zone_no, sum(PAYMENT_DATA.amount) as amount_sum from PAYMENT_DATA inner join USERS_TAXPAYER on \n" +
        "PAYMENT_DATA.tin_no = USERS_TAXPAYER.tin_no group by USERS_TAXPAYER.zone_no",nativeQuery = true)
List<ZoneWiseTotalAmountDto> countZoneWiseReturnAmount();
```

[image]

but now I want to retrieve this response as dto, I tried to follow the interface based projection , so I modified the code as follows-

```
public interface IZoneAmountDTO{
        Integer getZone();
        Double getAmount();
    }
    @Query(value = "select new com.example.nbr.entity.ZoneWiseTotalAmountDto(z.zone,z.amount) from (select USERS_TAXPAYER.zone_no, sum(PAYMENT_DATA.amount) as amount_sum from PAYMENT_DATA inner join USERS_TAXPAYER on \n" +
            "PAYMENT_DATA.tin_no = USERS_TAXPAYER.tin_no group by USERS_TAXPAYER.zone_no) z",nativeQuery = true)
    List<ZoneWiseTotalAmountDto> countZoneWiseReturnAmount();
```

below is my `ZoneWiseTotalAmountDto` class

```
package com.example.nbr.entity;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ZoneWiseTotalAmountDto {
    private Integer zone;
    private Double amount;

}
```

If I run it then Intellij says-

```
ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions - Incorrect syntax near '.'
```

What am I doing wrong here? Where to use that Interface that I created? I was following this blog- [link](https://roytuts.com/how-to-map-custom-query-results-into-dto-in-spring-data-jpa/)

Comment: I've been looking into that too. You need entity classes with import javax.persistence.Entity; with an AT=Entity defined class with coresponding db column fields (getter and setter methods) , AT=Id entity on one of the fields is for primary-key id column.. here's a good explaination of Entity classes  https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-entities  and projections , https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-projections

Comment: This appears to be a good one i found ()bindings and aliases and collective registration of the components)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29581515/why-is-my-projection-interface-not-picked-up-by-spring-data-rest  you need to do some binding and setting of the interfaces with the entity classes and  persistent data and the JPA repositories of that data cohesively.

Comment: Your public interface IZoneAmountDTO{ should be a "nested interface" it says inside your tutorial link and its outer should extend  extends JpaRepository<Event, Integer> with the angle brackets for a return row in some type of List or Collection form.  extends JpaRepository<WhatYouPut , Integer>  the integer is for the id key of the row.

Comment: You are saying that code you pasted here is now your DTO class code !!!  compare it to the DTO source code from the download link of the tutorial  page link you posted  GitHub SRC https://github.com/roytuts/spring-jpa/blob/master/spring-data-jpa-native-query-to-dto/src/main/java/com/roytuts/spring/data/jpa/natve/query/dto/EventDto.java